# gRPC in Java - How to recieve file content as response

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I'm new to gRPC programming. I need to write a gRPC client which receives file content sent from the gRPC server and send this content to web-page. As the file content is huge, I've set it as a stream.
Below is my .proto file

```
service LogService {    
    rpc fetchLogContent(LogRequest) returns (stream LogResponse);
}

message LogRequest {
    string ip = 1;
    string fileName = 2;
}

message LogResponse {
    string ip = 1;
    string logContent = 2;
}
```

Now, in the client, when I use the blockingStub to access fetchLogContent, it returns an Iterator . I understand from the examples provided [grpc.io - java](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/java.html), if there are list of response objects, (list of Feature objects in the example provided in link), an Iterator will be valid. But in my case, I need a single LogResponse which was sent as a stream. Please provide any suggestions/alternatives for this. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Method definition:

```
rpc fetchLogContent(LogRequest) returns (stream LogResponse);
```

The `stream` keyword means that you will get 0 or more LogResponse messages.  If the content is very large, what you can do is read chunks of the file (like 4kb) and send multiple LogResponse messages each with a part of the file.  The client side can read the chunks repeatedly, and piece it back together.

Since the `ip` field will likely not be changing each time, you can make you server only set `ip` on the first message.  On the client, just use the very first ip received.